# How to DELETE a line(s) in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am new to file-handling...

I am writing a program that saves data in text-files in the following format:

```
         3740541120991
        Syed Waqas Ali
        Rawalpindi
        Lahore
       12-12-2012
         23:24
           1
            1
```

(Sorry for the bad alignment, it's NOT a part of the program)

Now I'm writing a delete function for the program that would delete a record.
So far this is my code:

```
void masterSystem::cancelReservation()
{

string line;
string searchfor = "3740541120991";
int i=0;

ifstream myfile("records.txt");

while (getline(myfile, line))
{
    cout << line << endl;
    if (line==searchfor)
    {
                 // DELETE THIS + THE NEXT 8 LINES
    }
}
```

}

I've done a bit of research and have found out that there is no easy way to access the line of a text file so we have to create another text file. 
But the problem arises that how do I COPY the records/data before the record being deleted into the NEW text file?

Comment: load them into memory?

Comment: You're going to experience difficulties deleting *anything* from an `ifstream`. You're quite-write there is no silver bullet without content rewriting in some form from the point of the deleted data forward.

Comment: I agree with Ryan.  Load all line let say in a vector, delete the line from the vector and re-write the vector into a new file

Comment: I have no idea what a vector is 
Can you please tell me or point me to a helpful guide.?

Comment: The best place to learn what a vector is, outside of a book, is by googling for `vector c++ tutorial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a record per line and make even more easy for example:

`3740541120991|Syed Waqas Ali|Rawalpindi|Lahore|12-12-2012|23:24|1|1`

and the `|` character saparating each field. This is a well known technic knows as CSV (Comma separated Values)

This way you don't have to worry about reading consecutive lines for erase a record and add a record access the file only once.

So your code becoms into:

```
void masterSystem::cancelReservation()
{

    string line;
    string searchfor = "3740541120991";

    ifstream myfile("records.txt");

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
       // Here each line is a record
       // You only hace to decide if you will copy 
       // this line to the ouput file or not.
    }
}
```

Don't think only about removing a record, there are others operations you will need to do against this file `save a new record`, `read into memory` and `search`.

Think a moment about search, and having your current desing in mind, try to answer this: How many reservations exists for date 12-12-2012 and past 12:00 AM?

In your code you have to access the file **8 times** per record even if the other data is irrelevant to the question. But, if you have each record in a line you only have to access file 1 time per record.

With a few reservations the diference is near 0, but it grows exponentially (n^8).

Comment: You are right...
Your methodology is proving quite helpful 
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Open the input file; read one line at a time from the input file.  If you decide to want to keep that line, write it to the output file.  On the other hand, if you want to 'delete' that line, don't write it to the output file.